# How can I add the options of changing lists on one Sharepoint 2010 calendar?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I have a Sharepoint calendar that looks like [image: this] 

and I need to add a sidebar with a possibly jquery dropdown to select between the the different calendar lists so they are interchangeable.

[image]

Comment: You don't need to do that, you can use the overlay feature, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overlay-a-SharePoint-calendar-with-a-calendar-from-Exchange-or-SharePoint-4caebe59-3994-4a94-9322-b31abb8a5e9a?CorrelationId=63f1a80c-7af1-468d-93b8-b2a38a03aa56&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Thanks, That would be an idea however the client wants a list to the side where they can select each list. I suppose I could do that overlay and then put javascript in afterwards to make them only viewable if they are clicked.

Comment: That's exactly what the overlay does, present a list of calendar links to the left of the calendar to toggle through.

Comment: oh right, sorry for the confusion checking it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*It looks like @PirateEric already gave you the correct answer in the comments, but I'll add it as an answer for completeness' sake.*

**SharePoint already offers this functionality OOTB.** It's called a "Calendar Overlay", and it allows you to display events from multiple calendars on a single calendar.

To create a calendar overlay, go to the calendar you want to use as a base. In this example, I created a new calendar called "All Calendars", but you can call it "Company Calendar" or whatever you want. On that calendar, click on the Calendar tab at the top and then on Calendar Overlays in the ribbon:

[image]

Once you're on the Calendar Overlays screen, you'll be taken to the settings page for your new overlay. To add a calendar to the overlay, click "New Calendar".

[image]

You'll need to choose the color and location of each calendar this way. IIRC SP2010 limited you to the same web application, but SP2013 allows you to overlay calendars from other web applications, or even Exchange. Click OK when you're done, and then repeat this process for each calendar you want to add.

When you're done, click OK and you'll go back to the overlay calendar. It will automatically show each separate calendar as a choice on the left:

[image]

For more information, please see the [MS Office Support link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overlay-a-SharePoint-calendar-with-a-calendar-from-Exchange-or-SharePoint-4caebe59-3994-4a94-9322-b31abb8a5e9a?CorrelationId=63f1a80c-7af1-468d-93b8-b2a38a03aa56&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) @PirateEric provided in his comment.

Comment: Hello,    I apologize for taking so long to get back to you.  We just had a lot of testing to do and I got distracted. You're idea has worked except for some reason the calendar options on the left did not automatically get added. Could this be only a 2013 feature? I'll upload a snapshot of my screen and add it to my question. Thanks

Comment: @KieranHanna : I've only used it in 2013, but I think it was added with 2010. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: Hi, Yeah I've since found out it is supported in 2010 but it just wont work for me for some reason